# Carrierwave multiple image upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm using multiple file uploads from the master branch and PostgreSQL
My product model hast a string field called "images" and I can attach multiple images just fine.

What I can't figure out though,  how can I remove one image from the products? 
I can remove all images as described in the docs:

```
product.remove_images!
product.save
```

but didn't find a way how to remove a single image.

Comment: Do you have `images` or `image` as an attribute name?

Comment: "multiple file uploads from the master branch" - is there a gem in addition to carrierwave, or what do you mean by that?

Comment: check https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads 
where it says: Note: You must specify using the master branch to enable this feature:

Comment: @Pavan images is the attribute:
t.string  "images",  array: true

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a **nested form for** to try to delete an image?

Here is a piece of code from carrierwave's [github](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#removing-uploaded-files) site...

```
<%= form_for @product, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  .
  .
  .
    <label>
      <%= f.check_box :remove_images %>
      Remove images
    </label>
<% end %>
```

...which I am sure you have seen. Although, of course, calling `remove_images!` would not work in your case, since that implies a unified action on all images.

Try the following modification of the above and see if it helps you sort this problem and target each image individually...

```
<%= nested_form_for @product, :html=>{ :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  .
  .
  .
  <%= f.fields_for :images do |product_form|  %>

    <%= product_form.link_to_remove "Remove this image" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

To make this work make sure to include `gem 'nested_form', '~> 0.3.2'` in your Gemfile.

Hopefully this helps you out.

Comment: there is only one attribute, where should the nested form be used? if you read the readme on the master branch: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads 
I havea single column which stores an array. 

your solution would work if I had a separate model for the images, which I don't.

I started to look at the mount_multiple_spec.rb from carrierwave and I'm starting to think that there is now way.

Answer (score 1):

I learn from @Cris and use the following code snippet when working with S3.

```
def remove_image_at_index(index)
  remain_images = @product.images # copy the array
  deleted_image = remain_images.delete_at(index) # delete the target image
  deleted_image.try(:remove!) # delete image from S3
  @product.images = remain_images # re-assign back
end
```

I wrote a [blog post](http://bobintornado.github.io/rails/2015/12/29/Multiple-Images-Uploading-With-CarrierWave-and-PostgreSQL-Array.html) about this , and create a [sample project](https://github.com/bobintornado/sample-gallery-app-with-carrierwave) with more concrete codes.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `remove_image` on the specified image (from the array). So you'll need to somehow identify the image first (ex. `images[0].remove_image!`)

Answer (score 0):

adding something like this to the product model does the trick.

```
  def delete_image(idx)
    remaining_images = []
    self.images.each_with_index { |img,ii| remaining_images<<File.open(img.path) unless idx == ii}
    self.images=remaining_images
  end
```

Carrierwave also takes care of removing the file after saving the record.